# Mirror scrolling of UICollection

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

I have created a UICollection with a custom layout to allow for scrolling both vertical and horizontal.  It is a grid of equal sections and items in each section (ie 10 x 10, 20 x 20, etc).  I would like to be able to put two headers that remain in view, one along the top and one along the left side.  I have not found a way to do this within the UICollection itself.  So, I set up UICollection along the left and another along the top.  However, as the user scrolls the grid left and right and/or up and down, I want these two collections to mirror those movements.

So, my question is: Is there a way to mirror the horizontal movement of the main UICollection to the top UICollection and then mirror the vertical movement of the main UICollection to the side UICollection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out.  Using self.mainCollectionView.contentOffset always returned (0,0), so tried to use the object name I actually assigned to it through the Storyboard and the view controller.  This worked.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self synchronizeCollectionViewContentOffsets];
}

-(void)synchronizeCollectionViewContentOffsets {
    CGPoint offset = myCollectionView.contentOffset;
    myLeftMargin.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offset.y);
    myTopMargin.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offset.x, 0);
}
```

Where myCollectionView, myLeftMargin and myTopMargin are linked to the UICollectionViews through the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  It sends its delegate all of the messages defined in the [`UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).

The message you want to respond to is [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a).  When your main collection view sends this message, you want to respond to it by getting its `contentOffset` and applying the offset to your margin collection views as appropriate.

```
// Implement this in your main collection view's delegate.
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self synchronizeCollectionViewContentOffsets];
}

- (void)synchronizeCollectionViewContentOffsets {
    CGPoint offset = self.mainCollectionView.contentOffset;
    self.leftMarginView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offset.y);
    self.topMarginView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offset.x, 0);
}
```

Comment: When the view first shows up, it automatically scrolls to a specific cell in the main UICollectionView, this does hit the scrollViewDidScroll method, which then hits the synchronize method; however, the offset point that is created in the first line is basically 0,0 even when the point it scrolled to is not even close to that.  This is the case when I try to scroll through the grid as well.  The offset point created is always 1.343243x-34 or something like that.